# Printing the same contiguous lines only once using shell/awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have an input as below:

```
Sep 9 09:22:11
Hello
Hello
Sep 9 10:23:11
Hello
Hello
Hello
Sep 10 11:23:11
```

I expect the output as below: (the same contiguous lines are replaced by only one line)

```
Sep 9 09:22:11
Hello
Sep 9 10:23:11
Hello
Sep 10 11:23:11
```

Could anyone help me solving this one fast using shell or awk ?

Answer (score 1):

Using awk you can do this:

```
awk '$0 != prev; {prev=$0}' file

Sep 9 09:22:11
Hello
Sep 9 10:23:11
Hello
Sep 10 11:23:11
```

**Command Breakup:**

```
$0 != prev;   # if previous line is not same as current then print it
{prev=$0}     # store current line in a variable called prev
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove repeats of lines, use `uniq`:

```
uniq File
```

With your sample input, for example:

```
$ uniq File
Sep 9 09:22:11
Hello
Sep 9 10:23:11
Hello
Sep 10 11:23:11
```

Although its name may imply that `uniq` concerns itself with unique lines, it does not: it looks for adjacent repeated lines and, by default, removes the repeats.

Comment: You are right. I though that this command does not look for adjacent repeated lines. Actually, it works well. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Just because you asked for shell too, though the given answers are all better solutions -

```
last=''
while read line
do if [[ "$line" -eq "$last" ]]
   then continue
   else echo "$line"
        last="$line"
   fi
done < infile
```

This is simple, clear, and likely slower than either `awk` or `uniq`.